# Horizontal spacing in "align" mode

Tags: spacing, align

I write gamma symbol with indices in normal math mode as follows;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$
\Gamma^{\alpha} \\ _{\mu \nu}
$$

\end{document}
```

This is the right placement of indices I want. But when I use the same spacing command "\\" in align mode, it breaks the line instead of putting same horizontal space. I don't want to use other spacing commands like "\," since they put more spaces then I want. My question is: Is there a way that I can put the same amount of horizontal space as "\\" to the same place in my gamma symbol in align mode? I will be glad if you can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\\` inside `\[...\]` (which is to be preferred over `$$...$$`) is not allowed and it indicates the end of line if ever allowed. To leave a space you can use an empty atom `{} like

```
{\alpha}{}_
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[               %% no blank line to be left
%$$              %% don't use $$
\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu \nu} \text{ and }\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{\mu \nu}
%$$
\]
\end{document}
```

You can also use `\,` as in `{\alpha}\,_` though, Id not recommend it.